# CakePHP: "IN"-operator works differently for single value and multiple values

Tags: cakephp, in-operator

I am using this query to fetch matching results:

```
$result = $this->Customer->CustomersC->find('list', array(
  'conditions' => array('CustomersC.company_id IN' => $companyIds),
  'fields' => array('CustomersC.customer_id'),
));
```

If `$companyIds` has more than one value the query works perfect. Here's query printed in log:

> SELECT `CustomersC`.`customer_id` FROM `project`.`customers_companies` AS `CustomersC`   WHERE `CustomersC`.`company_id` IN (7, 8, 9, 11, 15)

However, if `$companyIds` has only one value, it throws an SQL exception. Here's the query:

> SELECT `CustomersC`.`customer_id` FROM `project`.`customers_companies` AS `CustomersC`   WHERE `CustomersC`.`company_id` IN = ('7')

Please note the unnecessary = (equalTo operator) added after **IN**.

Can someone point me in right direction for handling this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify `IN` in your conditions. You just need to do the following:-

```
$result = $this->Customer->CustomersC->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('CustomersC.company_id' => $companyIds),
    'fields' => array('CustomersC.customer_id'),
));
```

CakePHP will determine whether you mean `=` or `IN` by the value of the condition. If you're passing an array it will treat the condition as an `IN`. In your broken case it is using `=` but you've got `IN` in your condition key, resulting in the `IN =` error.